# Какие из этих слов являются однокоренными слову "свергнуть"?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

1. изверг
2. приверженцы
3. отвергать
4. извержение

Comment: Сделайте свое предположение, пожалуйста...

Answer (score 1):

Тут надо правильно извлечь корень из слова СВЕРГНУТЬ.Либо тут в основе лежит очень древний корень всего из 2х букв-ВР(сверло, ответстие,ворота,врать,вертеть и тд-это как ни странно однокоренные по происхожд. слова) а это всегда вращение или еще смысл перемены свергнуть это когда у власти один убирает другого и сам встает на его место, либо корень ,,ВЕР,, от слова ВЕРА тогда СВЕРГНУТЬ означает перестать верить человеку.Вот в чем тут загвостка.